# Change global tint color programmatically DURING RUNTIME iOS8, Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

Are there any opportunities to change the global tint color of an ios8 App during runtime programmatically? I only know the AppDelegate - Possibility, but this isn't during runtime.

Comment: Maybe you can subclass your ViewControllers to inherit from a custom one , and make the changes you want in there. Then you can programmatically make the change.

Comment: What do you mean that the AppDelegate isn't during runtime?

Comment: During the App is running, the user should have the possibility to change the global tint color. The modification should happen WITHOUT restarting the App. @rmaddy

Comment: I get that. It's just that your statement that the AppDelegate isn't available during runtime makes no sense. Regardless, what have you tried so far? Update your question with relevant code and details.

Comment: I only have tried to change the tint color with the window variable in AppDelegate. But I don't know how to change this variable during runtime... I have tried `AppDelegate().window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()` but this do not work ... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the window's `tintColor` in code in response to the user's desire. The change will propagate down the whole interface immediately.

Comment: What do you mean? I have tried `AppDelegate().window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()` but this doesn't work ... :-(

Comment: Oh thank you! I am new to Xcode at all, thereby I am asking as stupid questions....